# Angular2 RxJS - Multiple HttpGet - Notify me when they all complete

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have  a component that makes 3 separate http calls.  Once all 3 calls complete I want to perform an action (hide my loading bar).

I think the *.concat* operator is the solution but I am having trouble figuring out how to use it.  I only want my http calls to execute once, but because I have multiple .subscribe() calls (original call, and concat) I understand why my http calls are being made 2X.  I just dont know how to code it. Maybe I need *forkJoin?* *.Concat*?

**My Current Angular2 Component.ts** - makes http calls 2X

```
const form$ = this.myService.getSubmissionForm(this.submissionId);        
this.subscription = form$
    .subscribe((submissionForm: SubmissionForm) => {                    
        this.submissionForm = submissionForm;                               
    },
    (error: any) => {  },       /* Error */ 
    () => {  });                /* Complete success*/ 

const comments$ = this.myService.getComments(this.submissionId);
this.subscription = comments$.subscribe(
    (comments: Comment[]) => {                
        this.submissionComments = comments;
    });

const documents$ = this.myService.getRelatedDocuments(this.submissionId);
this.subscription = documents$.subscribe(
    (viewModel: SubmissionDocumentsSection) => {
        this.submissionDocumentSection = viewModel;
    });

// Inform any listeners that our async calls have all completed.
const combined$ = Observable.concat(form$, comments$, documents$);
combined$.subscribe(
    () => { },
    (error: any) => {                
        this.ngInitLoadComplete.emit(false);               
    },
    () => {                
        this.ngInitLoadComplete.emit(true);               
    });
```

**What I Think I Want.ts**

```
const form$ = this.myService.getSubmissionForm(this.submissionId);          
const comments$ = this.myService.getComments(this.submissionId);
const documents$ = this.myService.getRelatedDocuments(this.submissionId);

// Inform any listeners that our async calls have all completed.
const combined$ = Observable.concat(form$, comments$, documents$);

/** Bad syntax here! How do I subscribe and get results? **/
combined$.subscribe(
    (submissionForm: SubmissionForm ,
     comments: Comment[],
     viewModel: SubmissionDocumentsSection  ) => {
        this.submissionForm = submissionForm;          
        this.submissionComments = comments;
        this.submissionDocumentSection = viewModel;
    },
    (error: any) => {                
        this.ngInitLoadComplete.emit(false);               
    },
    () => {                
        this.ngInitLoadComplete.emit(true);               
    });
```

My syntax is not correct and I am having trouble finding a solution. 
How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use `Observable.forkJoin` to combine the requests and then use the data in a single callback.

From the [docs](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/forkjoin.md), `Observable.forkJoin` *runs all observable sequences in parallel and collect their last elements.*

Like so:

```ts
Observable.forkJoin([
            this.myService.getSubmissionForm(this.submissionId),
            this.myService.getComments(this.submissionId),
            this.myService.getRelatedDocuments(this.submissionId)])
            .subscribe((data: [SubmissionForm, Comment[], SubmissionDocumentsSection]) => {
                this.submissionForm = data[0];          
                this.submissionComments = data[1];
                this.submissionDocumentSection = data[2];
            },
            (error: any) => {                
                this.ngInitLoadComplete.emit(false);               
            },
            () => {                
                this.ngInitLoadComplete.emit(true);               
            });
```

## Edit

Each call to a method on `myService` returns an observable. These observables can be used more than once, if you use the [Share](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/8fa95ac884181fb6cbff8ce7c1d669ffb190f5e4/doc/api/core/operators/share.md) operator, so you can subscribe to them and join them to know when they all complete.

This is how you can perform actions after each individual observable returns and once they all complete:

```ts
let formObservable = this.myService.getSubmissionForm(this.submissionId).share();
let commentsObservable = this.myService.getComments(this.submissionId).share();
let docsObservable = this.myService.getRelatedDocuments(this.submissionId).share();

formObservable.subscribe((submissionForm: SubmissionForm) => {                    
    this.submissionForm = submissionForm;                               
});

commentsObservable.subscribe((comments: Comment[]) => {                
    this.submissionComments = comments;
});

docsObservable.subscribe((viewModel: SubmissionDocumentsSection) => {
    this.submissionDocumentSection = viewModel;
});

Observable.forkJoin([
            formObservable,
            commentsObservable,
            docsObservable])
            .subscribe(() => {},
            (error: any) => {                
                this.ngInitLoadComplete.emit(false);               
            },
            () => {                
                this.ngInitLoadComplete.emit(true);               
            });
```

Check out the [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/FUP7eP8B3sJWgtnDx8c9).

Comment: Thank you - I forgot to add that I'd still like to  know when each individual observable completes. So once the submissionForm completes, I'd like to capture that and perform an action as well while it's waiting for the others to complete.  Possible?

Comment: This brings me back to my original problem- duplicate http requests which is result of the multiple subscriptions.

Comment: In my case it is more important to avoid duplicate calls then it is to notify upon each individual completion so I will mark your original answer as correct .ForkJoin eliminates the duplicate calls.  You can probably remove the **Edit** since it does not solve the issue.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Updated my answer to use the `share` operator.